# Extracting subvector of a vector

Tags: matlab

I have a set of values (say 20 values) in an array .

```
 A = [1:20]
```

I want to divide it in to subsets of known size.
If I want to divide it in to 4 sets of size 5 then I can use

```
y = reshape(A,5,4)'
```

But my problem is when I dont have matching multiples of sizes.
Say I want to divide array in to sets of 3. So there will be 7 sets but the last set will be short.

what exactly I want is

```
a1= [1 2 3]

a2= [4 5 6]

a3= [7 8 9]

a4= [10 11 12]

a5= [13 14 15]

a6= [16 17 18]

a7= [19 20]
```

How can I do this kind of subgrouping to a vector in MATLAB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
y = mat2cell(A,1, diff([0:n:numel(A)-1 numel(A)]));
```

Then `a1=y{1}` and so on.

Comment: +1 Good use of Matlab functions that provide this functionality. Just to be clear, `n` is the max size of a subset. So, for your example, `n=3` would give `y{7}` to be `[19 20]`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write your own function for this.  For example:

```
A = 1:20;
n = length(A);
x = 3;
y = ceil(n/x);
out = cell(y,1);
for i = 1:y
  startIdx = x*(i-1)+1;
  endIdx = min(startIdx + x - 1,n);
  out{i} = A(startIdx:endIdx);
end
```

Then you can access each row in the cell array:

```
a1 = out{1};
a2 = out{2}; 
...
```

Comment: +1 You can use 1:x:length(A) instead of calculating `startIdx`, and `endIdx`. Other than that, a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = 1:20;
n = 3;

% y = number of sets
y = ceil(length(A) / n);

ai = num2cell(reshape(A(1:n*y),m,n)');
if length(A) > n * y
    ai = [ai; A(n*y+1:end)];
end
```